# how open chrome settings in new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settings

I want to open `"chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream"` in a new tab using JavaScript 
`window.location.href="chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream"` or `onclick="window.top.location='chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream'"` doesn't work
any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to load local resources, your best bet would be to inform the user how to reach that page in a nice way.